# Reverse SSL Proxy support

Tags: security, apache, nginx

I would like to use nginx as a reverse proxy in front of a Joomla site running on Apache. I would like nginx to handle the SSL connections and relay decrypted traffic through localhost  to Apache.

Does Joomla have specific support for this type of configuration, such that I can still have it control which pages should be served over SSL vs. unencrypted connections, or would I have to simply enable SSL across the board for this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pulling from non-Joomla SSL proxy experience here. However, I believe it will work.

1. Configure nginx to send an `X-FORWARDED-PROTO` header with a value of "https"

   ```
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
   ```
2. Configure Apache to set the HTTPS environment variable to "on":

   ```
   SetEnvIfNoCase X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
   ```

Once you have those configured, Joomla should be able to figure out what's going on and adjust URLs accordingly.

Comment: Nginx dynamic forwarded protocol using variable:

 `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;`